# Asterisk Media service with opensips

Tags: linux, voip

Hi I am integrating Asterisk with OpenSIPS as media services, I am testing with Asterisk conference and voicemail, but I have a problem when I call a conference call is dropped after 30 seconds.

Opensips and asterisk in the same box

Opensips 5060
Asterisk 5080

[image: My logs]
in log appears like NAT issues, but both are in the same box and all my local customers UA are not remote

my config opensips.cfg

http://www.netsoluciones.com/opensip.txt

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I can't see which packet is it complaining about, but I'm assuming that the server doesn't see `ACK` from the client - if it's the conference service the caller will send `INVITE`, Asterisk will answer `200/OK` and caller is supposed to send `ACK`. `200/OK` would be the "critical packet" mentioned in the logs.

Try tracing all connections separately. Make sure that OpenSips transfers the ACK correctly (it can be tricky to implement, make sure both strict and loose route variants are handled). Make sure OpenSips doesn't try to rewrite contact field if it's a local network scenario.

Comment: Thnk viraptor for your quick response , maybe you could see my opensips.cfg code, and help me find the error.

Comment: Add it to the question, it can't hurt :)

Comment: guys OpenSIPS upload my settings to help me find the problem, I add it to the beginning of the post

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a common issue.

The problem is with your RTP transport - has nothing to do with your signaling on ports 5060 or 5080. While I cannot see the packet itself, you are getting an RTP timeout - and asterisk default RTP timeout is 30 seconds.

Couple things to check.

1. Make sure that the endpoint where you are sending the media (the RTP stream itself - UDP ports 10000 - 60000) is allowed in the remote firewall.
2. Make sure that you are accepting all UDP RTP ports from the remote systems - this can be tricky and I usually recommend allowing all UDP ports from 1025 to 60000 on an SBC such as the one that you have - it is not risky as you cannot place or receive a call without signaling (which you have protected on ports 5060-5080).
3. As the previous commenter stated, check NAT and make sure that the external IP is in the SIP packet properly.  If you would like, type the following at in the asterisk CLI:

   sip set debug on

then paste the contents of the debug in reply to this and I can assist further.

1. You can also set the rtpignoreversion attribute within asterisk. But I would only recommend this as a last resort. Best to paste the SIP trace, as instructed above, to get to the root of the issue.

If I was a bettin' man - and sometimes I am :-)  - I would bet dollars to doughnuts that the RTP (media) stream is not passing properly between that server and the endpoint it is communicating with. A SIP trace will show you the problem IP address and, I would bet, allow you to either open the firewall to allow said endpoint AND/OR persuade you to open RTP to that server by opening the UDP ports referenced above.  If IPTABLES is turned on, try and disable it and test.  Again, a SIP trace will tell us everything we need to know to give you the exact answer.

UPDATE AFTER SEEING YOUR LOGS ----

It looks like to me your routing script doesn't have the hooks necessary to bind asterisk in the way that you want...

Take a look at this script - I have used this in the past. It will require some modification on your part, but it should get you going...

Obviously this is not an entire routing script - it would be placed just before your route definitions near the bottom of your script...

Also - you did catch the fact that asterisk could not authenticate user 3012, right?  I am assuming you did and that it not relevant to your question, but I thought I should ask...

```
# ASTERISK HOOK - BEGIN
        # media service number? (digits starting with *)
    if ($rU=~"^\*[1-9]+") {
        # we do provide access to media services only to our
        # subscribers, who were previously authenticated 
        if (!is_from_local()) {
            send_reply("403","Forbidden access to media service");
            exit;
        }
        #identify the services and translate to Asterisk extensions
        if ($rU=="*1111") {
            # access to own voicemail IVR
            seturi("sip:VM_pickup@ASTERISK_IP:ASTERISK_PORT");
        } else
        if ($rU=="*2111") {
            # access to the "say time" announcement 
            seturi("sip:AN_time@ASTERISK_IP:ASTERISK_PORT");
        } else
        if ($rU=="*2112") {
            # access to the "say date" announcement 
            seturi("sip:AN_date@ASTERISK_IP:ASTERISK_PORT");
        } else
        if ($rU=="*2113") {
            # access to the "echo" service
            seturi("sip:AN_echo@ASTERISK_IP:ASTERISK_PORT");
        } else
        if ($rU=~"\*3[0-9]{3}") {
            # access to the conference service 
            # remove the "*3" prefix and place the "CR_" prefix
            strip(2);
            prefix("CR_");
            rewritehostport("ASTERISK_IP:ASTERISK_PORT");
        } else {
            # unknown service
            seturi("sip:AN_notavailable@ASTERISK_IP:ASTERISK_PORT");
        }
        # after setting the proper RURI (to point to corresponding ASTERISK     extension),
        # simply forward the call
        t_relay();
        exit;
    }
    # ASTERISK HOOK - END

    # do lookup
    if (!lookup("location")) {
        # ASTERISK HOOK - BEGIN
        # callee is not registered, so different to Voicemail
        # First add the VM recording prefix to the RURI
        prefix("VMR_");
        # forward to the call to Asterisk (replace below with real IP and port)
        rewritehostport("ASTERISK_IP:ASTERISK_PORT");
        route(1);
        # ASTERISK HOOK - END
        exit;
    }

    # when routing via usrloc, log the missed calls also
    setflag(2);

    # arm a failure route in order to catch failed calls
    # targeting local subscribers; if we fail to deliver
    # the call to the user, we send the call to voicemail
    t_on_failure("1");

    route(1);
}


route[1] {
    if (!t_relay()) {
        sl_reply_error();
    };
    exit;
}


failure_route[1] {
    if (t_was_cancelled()) {
        exit;
    }

    # if the failure code is "408 - timeout" or "486 - busy",
    # forward the calls to voicemail recording
    if (t_check_status("486|408")) {
        # ASTERISK HOOK - BEGIN
        # First revert the RURI to get the original user in RURI
        # Then add the VM recording prefix to the RURI
        revert_uri();
        prefix("VMR_");
        # forward to the call to Asterisk (replace below with real IP and port)
        rewritehostport("ASTERISK_IP:ASTERISK_PORT");
        t_relay();
        # ASTERISK HOOK - END
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies, opened the ports on the firewall on and 1025:60000 10000:60000 udp, but the problem continues , I PASTE DE LOG of asterisk http://www.netsoluciones.com/sip_packet.txt , also turn off the firewall

Comment: Hi forum, again try to reproduce this scenario was the same as the OpenSIPS website and I have the same results.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that could drop a call.

I'll list 3 so you can take a look:

1) Unreceived ACK from Callee, will make it continuous generate 200 OK then quit and send BYE.

2) RTP Timeout

3) SIP ping mecanism of Opensips

Since you got a Retransmission timeout, I would go with number 1 and William answer is a good place to start.

I got several issues in the past running Opensips on local IP addresses... Can be a little tricky. 
Also, don't forget to use record_routing() on Main route of Opensips so you make sure that it stays in the middle of the conversation.

Comment: http://www.netsoluciones.com/sip_packet_opensips.txt , Hi, I'm no expert with OpenSIPS and I'm adapting to provide some services to my network users, but I'm stuck on this part, basically my scrips opensips.cfg is having multidomain and to integrate the messaging, and media service with asterisk